# Cannot install Realtek rtl8723be Drivers in kali linucx

Tags: kali-linux

I triet git cloning into https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/ but I got the following error`remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/' not found`

it looks like they removed the repo . can anyone help me or if anyone has already cloned it can he send me the zip version or anything? I really need the help. I tried everything but I couldnt get my wifi working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the new URL for the Realtek rtl8723be Linux driver:

https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de

Comment: The question asks for the rtl8723be driver, but your link points to the rtl8723de driver.

Comment: @rmutalik This driver supports rtl8723be as well.